# Celery workers receive the task but do not process it

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I’m trying to implement Celery and RabbitMQ in my Django project with poor results. So I’m trying to create a simple script that simply prints the result of the sum.

```
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep

app = Celery('tasck', broker='amqp://**_dev:***@204.***.***.43:5**2/ed_dev')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    sleep(5)
    z = x + y
    return f"return is {z}"
```

The result is never printed either in this simple script or inside the Django project

I expect that after receiving the task

```
[2023-04-30 22:14:51,388: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasck.add[c6711609-4da4-44a8-88f7-d78abdaeb7c6] received
```

Print the result, but as you can see below, no result is printed.

```
 -------------- celery@ACQUARIO01 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0 2023-04-30 22:14:46
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasck:0x118dca895d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://**_dev:***@204.***.***.43:5**2:5672/ed_dev
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasck.add

[2023-04-30 22:14:46,866: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://ed_dev:**@204.216.215.43:5672/ed_dev
[2023-04-30 22:14:46,929: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,262: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 19892 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,278: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 25156 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,281: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 27300 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,289: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 5412 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,318: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 26668 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,330: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 17096 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,331: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 5392 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,340: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 2680 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,364: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 25624 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,370: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 7892 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,382: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 18956 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,397: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 15212 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,400: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 28856 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,402: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 14972 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,421: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 25640 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,426: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 5148 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,910: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-17] child process 8736 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,923: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-18] child process 27288 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:47,924: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-19] child process 13752 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:48,143: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-04-30 22:14:48,224: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-20] child process 16812 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:48,382: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ACQUARIO01 ready.
[2023-04-30 22:14:51,388: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasck.add[c6711609-4da4-44a8-88f7-d78abdaeb7c6] received
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,351: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-21] child process 17752 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,356: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-22] child process 10396 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,368: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-23] child process 25396 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,374: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-24] child process 7952 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,377: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-25] child process 27488 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,389: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-28] child process 17312 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,394: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-27] child process 14072 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:52,396: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-26] child process 18568 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:53,111: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-30] child process 24804 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:53,111: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-29] child process 25416 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:53,120: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-31] child process 7956 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:53,923: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-32] child process 23032 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:53,928: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-33] child process 11852 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:54,717: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-34] child process 25580 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:55,529: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-35] child process 15468 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:56,329: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-36] child process 8180 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:57,141: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-37] child process 27240 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:57,959: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-38] child process 29432 calling self.run()
[2023-04-30 22:14:58,770: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-39] child process 21840 calling self.run()
```

Why do you think